# How to read multiple dictionaries in a text file?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have multiple dictionaries in a `doc.txt` file, for example:

```
Dic1={ "1" : "Value1" , "2" : "Value2" , "3" : "Value3"}
Dic2={ "1" : "Value4" , "2" : "Value5" , "3" : "Value6:}
...
Dic9={ "1" : "Value10" , "2" : "Value11" , "3" : "Value12:}
```

The goal is to read the file and split it into 9 dictionaries so I can access them.

Comment: What is the source of this file? What creates it? Why aren't you using an actual serialization format, like JSON or pickle? It is important to understand, the file *doesn't contain dictionaries*, it contains *text*.

Comment: I know that this file doesnt actually contain any dictionaries. The task though is to fill a txt file with these "Dictionaries", read it and then split it into actual dictionaries.

Comment: Now, if you trust the source of this file, you could just use `exec`, after reading the contents of the file into, say, `contents`, you can just do `data = {}; exec(content, data); del data['__builtins__']` and then `data['Dict1']` etc should work. But really, you should use an actual serialization format

Comment: @user18039945 what "task"? You didn't answer my question, **what is the source of this file**? If you are creating it, then you really should just use `json`.

Comment: Yes i am the one who creates the file

Comment: Then *don't* do `Dict1=...` whatever. *Use `json`*. Just a JSON array of objects (list of dicts) maybe, or on object with subobjects (dict of dicts)

Comment: Use JSON for this

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It is important for the community that you *also* demonstrate that you are working to solve your issue. The best way to do that in my opinion is to include the **text** based version of the source code you have so far, even if it is not working quite right.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
import json

dictionaries = []
with open(filename) as file:
    for line in file:
        dictionaries.append(json.loads(line[5:]))
```

And use your dictionnary like this (ex: for Dic1):

```
if dictionaries[1]["1"] == "Value1":
    # Do something
```

if you want more than 9 dict, you will need to name your dict with a constant number of character for example Dic003, Dic245, Dic034 etc. and change the "5" to correspond to the lenght of your names.

But this isn't the best way of doing that if you are the one that is creating the file.

A better way is to save the file with :

```
import json
data = [Dic1, Dic2, Dic3, Dic4, Dic5, Dic6, Dic7, Dic8, Dic9]
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```

And read it like this :

```
with open(filename) as f:
    dictionaries = json.load(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

change your file like that:

```
{ 
    "1": "Value1", 
    "2": "Value2", 
    "3": "Value3",
},
{ 
    "1": "Value4",
    "2": "Value5",
    "3": "Value6",
},
```

and then use ast module:

```
import ast

with open('doc.txt', 'r') as file:
    list = ast.literal_eval(f'[{file.read()}]')
    print(list)
    # output: [{'1': 'Value1', '2': 'Value2', '3': 'Value3'}, {'1': 'Value4', '2': 'Value5', '3': 'Value6'}]
```

now you will have a list of all your dictionaries and you can access to them by index like that:

```
dict1 = list[0]
dict2 = list[1]
print(dict1['1'], dict2['1'])
# output: Value1 Value4
```